how to write spl-associated-token-account this kinda instruction by solana/web3js?
https://solscan.io/tx/4s48QaCiKj6PwdCH1QjgAEfpoWFNEjv84puH8KMYxvHGqyxiCTMzmzVHafhqx8KW9ATXBhki5vXjGukrY5Z1kMPB
this tx assign a new generate account to a program and create a token account under this new account in one tx.how do i reconstruct this second instruction?

this is really make me confused,how create a token account of a new random generated account and applied it's token account publickey as a parameter in next instruction can be done in one tx

To me it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. The provided transaction involves 6 instructions in sum. The first creates the program account (Locked_voter: NewEscrow) and the second one creates the token account (Associated Token Account Program: Create). You can see the second instruction calls a program that do CPI calls. The associate token program should be here with the code which is invoked by submitting the (outer) instruction:  https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/v1.17/associated-token-account/program/src/processor.rs#L66
